# Why do we consider scheme-theoretic images?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Solving Problem 3.2.3 of Qing Liu,

If $f:X\to Y$ is a quasi-compact immersion, then $f$ can be decomposed by $i\circ u$ where $i$: closed immersion, $u$: open immersion.

If we can reduce this problem into affine case, the problem becomes easy I think.

More precisely, if we have the following situation;

$\mathrm{Spec}(A/J)_f \to \mathrm{Spec} A_f\to \mathrm{Spec} A$,

then we can take

$\mathrm{Spec}(A/J)_f \to \mathrm{Spec} A/J\to \mathrm{Spec} A$

as a desired factorization.

However, in the note of Madapusi(page 39, http://math.uchicago.edu/~keerthi/files/AG.pdf), they uses the *Scheme-theoretic image*. In other words, they take $I=\ker(A\to A_f/J_f)$ to make the scheme-theoretic image $\mathrm{Spec} A/I$ of $f$.

But, I cannot grasp the reason why they use it. Is it possible $I$ and $J$ being different? Without using the concept, is it not possible to solve this?

Comment: (1) It seems important to say how one would reduce to the affine case. I think that's where the hypotheses come in. (2) Non-equal ideals can certainly become equal when extended to the localization. If you pick $J$ to be the largest such then I think you're fine.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I think you are right. Without using the scheme-theoretic image, it might be tedious to reduce the case.